# How can I change that Rails code to make it work in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

A Rails gem titled `omniauth-ebay` which is compatible with Sinatra uses the code below to setup itself:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
       provider :ebay, "runame", "devid", "appid", "certid", "siteid", "apiurl"
    end
```

I know that `omniauth` (`omniauth-ebay` based on it) gem is definitely compatible with Sinatra. Note that that's not a eBay or gem specific question, there certainly should be a generic way to setup a middleware in Sinatra.

Well, how do I change the code above to make it work with Sinatra?

Comment: I have never used the above gem so not sure what the code of the above gem does  but still does this help `https://gist.github.com/3717973?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to understand what Rails is hiding from you. Rack middlewares are actually mounted directly inside of Rack.

In your config.ru file:

```
use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :ebay, "runame", "devid", "appid", "certid", "siteid", "apiurl"
end
```

The config.ru is loaded by Rack, so anything Rack-specific should go in there, unless you have some sort of system to put it elsewhere.  I suspect Sinatra probably allows you to call `#use` from inside your Sinatra application, but still, config.ru will work in all cases.